# Unable to install the curl or etc using Node NPM

Tags: node.js

I am creating some apps for my projects that is required to use NodeJS.. unfortunately, when i wanna install the curl into my desktop using npm, there is an error display -

```
/usr/local/bin/node: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

What is that mean? Do I need to re-install my node so that I can use as usual??

Comment: What command are you running to produce that? Just giving the error isn't very helpful.

Comment: already solved.. i've just need to re-install my node.. maybe there is some corrupted file or syntax that i can't fix.. huhuh

Comment: Cool, can you please close the question or write an answer so this doesn't stay unanswered?